# How to update a table according records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider this two tables :

**tbl 1**

```
Qsno      City  Status  Year    Month
--------------------------------------
1          01     3      1990     1
2          01     3      1990     1
1          02     3      1990     2
2          02     3      1990     2
1          03     3      1990     1
2          03     1      1990     1
3          03     1      1990     1
```

and :

**tbl 2**

```
Qsno      City  
---------------
 1          01   
 2          01   
 1          03   
 2          03   
 3          03
```

`Qsno` + `City` are unique

Ok, I want to update row from `tbl1` that has row in `tbl2` and set `Month = 3`.

How I can do this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update tbl1
set Month = 3
where exists
  (select *
   from tbl2
   where tbl1.Qsno = tbl2.Qsno and
         tbl1.City = tbl2.City)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this

```
use tempdb
go

create table #tbl1 (Qsno int,City int, intMonth int)
create table #tbl2 (Qsno int,City int)

insert into #tbl1 values (1,2,1),(1,3,1),(2,2,1),(2,3,1),(3,1,1)
insert into #tbl2 values (1,2),(2,2)

UPDATE t1
SET intMonth=3
FROM #tbl1 t1
     JOIN #tbl2 t2 ON t1.Qsno=t2.Qsno AND t1.City=t2.City

SELECT * FROM #tbl1

DROP TABLE #tbl1
DROP TABLE #tbl2
```

And don't use reserved words such as `Month`, `Year`, `Status` etc as names of Tables and Columns thus you will avoid a lot of headaches.